# Dynamic associations with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations, rails-activerecord

I am a little bit confused in defining the model design for the current project I am working on.

It's a sport team management app, so I can have teams from different sports adding players.  Since for each sport I want to store different information for the players, I have thought on having the following model.

```
A team:
-> has_many soccer_players
-> has_many basketball_players
-> ...
```

But this seems repetitive and I will just have lots of has_many, one for each sport type.  My question is, since at the time a User creates a team, he will choose the sport type, I would just need to define an association. So if the team is a soccer team, I would just need the '`has_many soccer_players`'.

How could I do that? Or even better, how would I model this in a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what Zippie offered and what you have asked in the comment I offer a slightly modified version.

I'll break it down to phrases and then into ruby classes and associations,
so if you want to make it truely polymorphic,

- A Team has many Players
- A Team has many Team Attributes
- A Player has
  many Attributes

It might simplify some parts of our application.
Team model itself for validations and such.
You'd have to decide what are generic attributes and what are dynamic, for instance name, weight, height are generic because all players have them, so they can be inside your `Player` model and not inside your `Attribute` model.

So we can now have something of the sort of:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :attributes, :as => :attributable
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :attributes, :as => :attributable
  attr_accessible :name, :weight, :height
end

class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attributable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :name, :value
end
```

As of your other question

You would have one table of attributes, one table of players and one of teams essentially.
Creating a football team and players (football = soccer yes?) would be like so (let's decide we already created a team):

```
player = Player.new
player.name = 'Lionel Messi'
player.attributes << Attribute.create!(:name => :playing_position, :value => :second_striker)
@team.players << player
@team.attributes << Attribute.create!(:name => :uefa_cups, :value => 4)
```

Your migration would look something like this (taken from Rails Guides directly - with minor changes):

```
class CreateAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :attributes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :value
      t.references :attributable, :polymorphic => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i really have to check the polymorphic associations in Rails

Comment: Guy, thanks for the answer.  I fail to see how would this work though. Say I want to create a new Soccer Team and some Soccer Players. Could you help me with that? Also, what about the migrations, would I need as many tables as sport types? I am a little bit confused about this "attributable".

Comment: So, the attributes would not be defined anywhere? They would be created on "run time".  I mean, say I wanted to list all the attributes that Soccer players have. That would not be possible taking this approach right?  Also, if I wanted to access to the playing_position of 'Lionel Messi' I would need to find if there is an attribute called that way for that Player, right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am saying this comment because I see confusing the fact of not having predefined attributes for players of a specific sport type. Imagine that I want to create a form to insert a Soccer Player, which fields would I put there? Maybe is a completely different approach, but is hard to see.

Comment: It can be done but it's up to you how to validate that, perhaps it could be frontend validation, perhaps you could have another table that stores each sport player attributes and team attributes and have to validate those.
As for the second question you could "attack" it from a few directions, you can either `Attribute.find_by_attributable_id_and_name(:attributable_id => Messi.id, :name => :playing_position).value`

OR

`Messi.attributes.where(:name => :playing_position).value`

OR
You could metaprogram inside the Model with `def missing_method` dynamic filter and do it a la Ruby way, savvy?

Comment: @Guy well, this just seems really new to me. Never done polymorphic associations. I might give it a try and see...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

team:

```
has_many :type_of_sports, :through => type_of_sport_on_team
has_many :players, :through => types_of_sports
```

type_of_sport:

```
has_many :teams, :through => type_of_sport_on_team
has_many :players
```

type_of_sport_on_team:

```
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :type_of_sport
```

player:

```
belongs_to :type_of_sport
```

after additional info:

```
Class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :name, :surname, :age
end

Class BasketballPlayer < Player
     attr_accessible :free_throw_average
end

Class SoccerPlayer < Player
     attr_accessible :penalty_scores
end
```

Comment: Zippie where would I store the specific information for a player in a specific sport? I mean, imagine that for soccer I want to store attribute_1 and attribute_2, and for basketball I want to store attribute_3 and attribute_4

Comment: using class inheritance? having a player and a subclass of basketball_player and soccer player with their own extra attributes

Comment: Zippie, how would you model that is my question. That's actually my main concern in this question...